# How do I get a coordinated frequency assigned for my repeater?

Tags: united-states, repeater

I am thinking about putting up a 70cm repeater up on my High School, where they have a very tall roof.

By the time It is ready to put it up, I want to make sure a frequency is reserved for the repeater.

Who do I contact / where can I get a frequency coordinated for the repeater?

I am located in Denver, Colorado, USA.

Answer (score 3):

I see you're from the United States based on your call sign, so let me answer the question for the US first, and then let me give a few indicators as to how you might do this across the world. In the United States, repeater frequencies are coordinated by a body known as the [National Frequency Coordination Council](http://nfcc.us/). Visiting their web site, you can find a frequency coordinator for your given state. Talk to the frequency coordinator, and make sure you are operating on the correct frequency.

As for outside of the United States, you need to either consult your government, or look for a similar frequency coordination council.

Comment: While this is the correct answer, please be aware that - in some areas - getting a frequency pair is more about who you know than any particular need or interest. There are many frequencies here in the eastern Great Lakes area marked as allocated which haven't seen a live repeater for years.

Answer (score 1):

Contact the CCARC.net folks - they run the repeater coordination here in Colorado. That said, my understanding is that there are no available allocations in either the 2m or 440 bands, except for some room for digital (MotoTRBO or DSTAR) modes. That said, reach out to them, their web page lists  http://www.ccarc.net/wordpress/coordination-support/ as the place to go to request a coordination.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that you do not need to have a repeater coordinated with one of the local repeater coordinators, they exist to minimize interference with others.  Think of them as a traffic cop at an intersection with a signal malfunctioning.
I do believe there are shared frequency pairs for testing and low power operation.  I can not remember the pairings.
I'm going through the same process myself for 70cm.

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to request a coordinated pair when using dead or quiet frequencies in 432.100 to 433.00 and 442.00 to 450.00 - huge sub-bands to choose within without causing QRM with a 15KHz bandwidth. Make sure no repeater use is taking place for continuous 20 minutes on the output freq (per ARRL Operation Manual) over a sensible sample of time frames. Ensure that none of the NON-Amateur first priority allocations (e.g. Radiolocation) are QRL on the freq. Check a current repeater database to avoid frequencies already coordinated in the coverage area.  Before repeater access is granted, do a test phase where the repeater automatically makes itself heard every 15 minutes at low power at first (25w) then increased in steps to 100w (keeping it local to the district). Announce with "This is WA0XXX the Central High School official student party line repeater, yo, in test mode currently. PL tone is 131.8, and we're all about the positivity on input! Control Operator or Station Licensee can be reached or left a message at (xxx)xxx-xxxx". Since you don't want the repeater used by non-students and non-faculty, the PL tone could be left out, to at least delay LID intrusion. Remaining uncoordinated and out of the database will assist in this regard. However once established, then is a good time to become coordinated.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I am a Ham Radio Operator of 25 years. PER THE FEDERAL LAW covering amateur radio, PART 97, (get a copy and read it) There is NO law that says You can't set up a repeater unless it is coordinated by a local council or anyone else. You look on your frequency allocation chart from the FCC and you look at the frequencies that the FCC says you can use for repeaters. Make sure you listen to that pair of frequencies for at least 30 days and make sure nobody comes along and tries to use it. You can even do this with two frequencies from a repeater that nobody has been heard using for 30 days. The law does not even have to say you have to do these last two things but it would be a good idea. But no Ham Radio Operator can ever have any kind of ownership of any frequency. As long as you are not intentionally interfering with another ham while he or she is talking, A Ham radio operator has a right to talk on any Ham radio freq anywhere with a set aside use for voice usage by the FCC.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com.  Please know that this site has a different format from a typical chat-style forum.  Our goal is to collect questions and their answers, and sort out the best answers.  Please take [the tour](http://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) to get the idea.  You might be technically correct that Part 97 doesn't require coordination, but your post doesn't answer the question, which was about how to request a coordinated frequency pair.  We're glad you're here and we'll look forward to more from you, but please respect the goal of this site.  73!

Comment: I'd much rather ask for a coordinated frequency pair than monitor a bunch of frequencies for 30 days to see which ones are being used.  Plus, coordinated frequencies are less likely to receive interference from other repeaters in the future.  Lastly, going through a frequency coordinator is generally considered to be good manners in the ham community.